# XMPPFramework pod cocoapods

Tags: xcode, xmppframework, cocoapods

I could not find a pod for the XMPPFramework, only for some extract. It would be awesome if someone could add a pod for that.
Here is a link to the GitHub account:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Thank you so much. I'm loving CocoaPods since I found out about them a few weeks ago. Not super familiar with them so I wouldn't want to create the pod myself. So thank you to whoever could create this. :)

Comment: We are currently working on it, I'll comment here when it's done

Answer (score 5):

We, @processone, fixed and pushed a revised version of [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/processone/XMPPFramework) (3.6.6) witch fix the circular dependency error, and add support to Swift.

Just add `pod 'XMPPFramework'` in your `Podfile` and you're good to go.

Comment: i added xmppframework 3.6.6 using cocoapods but found that there is no support for filetransfer in this.how to fix this and add support for filetransfer

Comment: @sujith1406, maybe this github repo will help https://github.com/nplexity/xmpp-file-transfer-demo

Comment: Can I select which XEP Extension that I wish to include on my XMPPFramework pod installation?

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf, Unfortunately you cannot do this.

Comment: @Loegic Oh. Thanks for the confirmation mate. The matter is apparently XEP 0054 make my build progress stucked. I've been asked a question about it and no one answered yet. :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326664/can-i-pod-xmppframework-without-all-of-its-xep-extension

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf I'll have a look

Answer (score 2):

The [CocoaPods specs](http://github.com/cocoapods/specs) are actually maintained by the community. If you would like to use this library with CocoaPods you actually add it yourself. You can run `pod spec create URL` to create a template that you can start the spec from ([docs](http://docs.cocoapods.org/commands.html#pod_spec_create)). Regardless I would say this is not a question for StackOverflow.