# Can I Pod XMPPFramework Without All of Its XEP Extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, cocoapods, xmppframework

I've been struggling for archiving my project recently. 2 hours passed and the archiving process still in *`Running 2 of 2 custom shell scripts`* phase.

[image]

Apparently, after looking into the **Report Navigator**, the root cause of this is because I am using **XMPPFramework** Pod and the archiving process took too long in running *Copy Pods Resources* custom shell script for one of **XMPPFramework Extensions XEP** (the one which I even don't use).
[image]

Then, I think I can get out from this trouble by **disabling** some XMPPFramework Extensions that I don't use.

So, with me using CocoaPods to install XMPPFramework to my project, can I remove XMPPFramework XEPs that I won't use? I only use 3 XEPs, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just install the XEP you want when using the pod.

You still have 2 options:

You can install the framework manually:
[Up to date instructions on how to install XMPPFramework manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091767/up-to-date-instructions-on-how-to-install-xmppframework-manually/30543948#30543948)

Or you can edit the XMPPFramework.h to use only the XEP you want, but I don't recommend this one.

Comment: Thanks mate. 
Since I know that I can select XEP I want when installing the framework manually, so I believe this is the solution.

But before I try installing the framework manually, I tried to update my Xcode 7.2.1 to Xcode 7.3. Then the problem I mentioned above was disappeared. So I keep going using your pod for XMPPFramework without any problem now. Thank you. :)